# Count, max, and multiple sub querys SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I'm currently working on a league systeme for my sport team. A ladder, as seen as in some video games.
It's a mobile web site, allowing coaches to create games, and monitor players performances.

I have games automatically balanced, taking into accounts player's experiences and points, then, i give bonus points to the all the players of the winner team, and remove points from the losers.

I have a relatively simple database. 3 tables.

> User : id - name
>
> Games : id - ETA - cration_date
>
> game_joueur: id- id_game - id_joueur - team - result - bonus

game_joueur beeing an assoc table, in wich i register  for each new game players id, the team he has been seeded on,  and afterwards, update the bonus field with the points earned and the result field with an integer (1 = lose, 2= win)

That way i can sum the bonus on my players stat and get the total points.

You can have a better look at the table here :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3e06/2

What i'm tryng to acomplish is for each player's stat page, retrieve from the database  the name of his most succesfull partner( the guy wich whom he won the most games), and also his worst ally , the men he lost the most match with.

This is what i do on my user stat page :

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(lad_game_joueur.result) FROM lad_game_joueur WHERE result = 1 AND lad_game_joueur.id_joueur = lad_user.id) as lose,
(SELECT SUM(lad_game_joueur.bonus) FROM lad_game_joueur WHERE lad_game_joueur.id_joueur = lad_user.id) as points,
lad_user.id as id , 
(SELECT COUNT(lad_game_joueur.result) FROM lad_game_joueur WHERE lad_game_joueur.id_joueur = lad_user.id AND result =2) as win,
lad_user.name 
FROM lad_user,lad_game_joueur 
WHERE  lad_game_joueur.id_joueur = lad_user.id AND lad_user.id
='.$id_joueur.' 
GROUP BY lad_user.id 
ORDER BY puntos DESC
```

I'm sure this is not the best way to do it, but it works :) ( i'm no sql specialist)

How can i tune this query to also retrive the informations i'm looking for?

I wont mind doing another query.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Ben

Comment: Images? Ewww! Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finealy found a way.
Here's what i did :

```
SELECT 
SUM(result)as result_sum, sum(Bonus) as bonus_sum, id_joueur 
from lad_game_joueur 
where result= 2 
and  id_game in 
(SELECT lad_game_joueur.id_game from lad_game_joueur,lad_game where id_joueur=2  
AND result= 2 and lad_game_joueur.id_game=lad_game.id)
 group by id_joueur 
order by result_sum DESC, bonus_sum desc
```

As you see, the sum of result would give me 4 if i won two games with the person, but i just divide by 2 on php and voilà :)

Comment: Yeah, that's not really a solution, is it ;-)